# MYSQL Select based on HTML select option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select

I have a select that is echoing out a column (jobTitle) from the database, on change I'm trying to display in another html select, selecting another column (company_name), but only values related to the first html select.

I'm not getting an errors. The first html select value is being passed, but for some reason it's not selecting from the db based on that in the second select.

I'm thinking the issue is with my second sql query.

P.S if anyone knows of a more effective way of doing this i'd be most gratefully to find out.

**PHP & HTML:**

```
<select name="jobtitle_select" class="jobtitle_select">
    <option class="" name="" value="" >-- Job title --</option> 
    <?php  
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list");
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        $jobTitle = $row['jobTitle'];
        echo "<option class='' name='' value='$jobTitle' > $jobTitle </option>"; 
    } // end of while //  ?>
</select>
<?php 
$jobtitle_select = $_POST['jobtitle_select'];
if ($jobtitle_select){
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE company_name = :jobtitle_select");
    $sql->bindParam(':jobtitle_select', $jobtitle_select, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
?>     
<select class="company_name_select" >   
    <option class="" name="" value="" >-- Company name --</option>      
    <?php while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        $company_name = $row['company_name'];
        echo "<option class='' name='' value='$company_name'> $company_name   </option>"; 
    } // end of while //        
}?>  <!-- end of if -->
</select>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.jobtitle_select').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST", 
            data:$('.jobtitle_select'),     
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(date){
                $('.company_name_select').html(date);
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is not correct, or better say not complete. You need to provide the url, and the posted variable with name and value.

```
$('.jobtitle_select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        url: "load_page.php",
        type: "POST", 
        data: {jobtitle_select: $('.jobtitle_select').val()},     
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(date){
            $('.company_name_select').html(date);
        }
    })
});
```

and your load_page.php  file should have the php of code to read data from the database and the html code to display only **the inner part of the select**:

```
<?php 
$jobtitle_select = $_POST['jobtitle_select'];
if ($jobtitle_select){
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE company_name = :jobtitle_select");
    $sql->bindParam(':jobtitle_select', $jobtitle_select, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
?>     

    <option class="" name="" value="" >-- Company name --</option>      
    <?php while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        $company_name = $row['company_name'];
        echo "<option class='' name='' value='$company_name'> $company_name   </option>"; 
    } // end of while //        
}?>  <!-- end of if -->
```

Comment: I don't need a url if i'm sending it to the same page. by defualt ajax sends it to the same page.

Comment: Above I have put piece of your code together to make it work. If you want to send the call to the same page then the `success` function is not correct because it loads the entire page into your `<select >`.

Comment: Good point, I tried this structure however the second html select is not being populated on change of the first, no errors

Comment: Can you post the exact code you tried?  Maybe a stupid question, but do you have data in the database to populate the second select? :)

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, seperated it in to two files, I added a html select with the `class="company_name_select"` and the ajax call above into the index file and the php above into the load_page.php and yes, I have data in the database :P

Comment: Can you check what you get returned by the ajax call? Use alert(date) or console.log(date) in your success function.

Comment: I can see in the Network tab -> Headers -> form data dropdown, that the data is being passed, however the alert shows only the html comment `<!-- end of if -->` from load_page.php

Comment: Do you have php error reporting enabled? Do you have included your php file all you what you need to connect to your database? This are some aspects I could think of for debugging.

Comment: Including the connection script in both files. tried var_dumping the `$sql` and  tried `print_r($sql->errorInfo());`